# Print vowels from the vector

Tags: r, sequence

I need to execute the vowels from the LETTERS R build-in vector

```
"A", "E", etc.

> LETTERS

  [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "U" 
   "V" "W" "X"
  [25] "Y" "Z"
```

Maybe, someone knows how to do it with if() or other functions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean removing the vowels? `LETTERS[!LETTERS %in% c('A','E','I','O','U')]` ?

Comment: No, just printing them separately, but with the use of LETTERS

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need extract vowels, does this work:

```
> vowels <- c('A','E','I','O','U')
> LETTERS[sapply(vowels, function(ch) grep(ch, LETTERS))]
[1] "A" "E" "I" "O" "U"
>
```